# Config File Sequence for ZSH?

Tags: shell, zsh, configuration

I know there is an elaborate sequence of config files that BASH reads sequentially (or alternatively skips if a particular one is present), however I have for the most part adopted ZSH as my default shell. I have tended to mainly edit my `~/.zshrc` for everything but I am wondering if I should be editing other files as well.

BTW I am often logging in to a non-graphical login shell on some machines so is there a different sequence for login ZSH sessions vs interactive ones?

Answer (score 2):

This is documented extensively in the `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES` section of the `zsh` man page.

Comment: It is also a prime example of man pages at their most cryptic. Not even referring to actual files but to environmental variable values. I can print out the env variable values but was hoping for practical experience with what people do.

Comment: The only environment variable used in that section is `$ZDOTDIR`, and the default value for that is explained right there. Your question didn't ask for practical experience, only what the sequence is.